# How to fix this error in drupal: ajax: ajax.form.ajaxSubmit is not a function

Tags: 7, ajax

I am creating a form with ajax submission in my Drupal custom form module.

When I click my submit button, I get the following error:

> ajax: ajax.form.ajaxSubmit is not a function.

I am searching some blogs, try something like uninstalling lightbox2 module, color box module, etc. But again the same error is displayed.

How can fix this error?

**Note**: I installed Lightbox first, but after this error I uninstalled it again.

Comment: Do you have jquery update or ligthbox installed ?

Comment: I think you haven't included jquery form plugin . ajaxSubmit is not a core jquery function,

Comment: try `drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.form');`

Comment: @NikhilM where I use this code

Comment: in the init of the custom module or in the form page.

Comment: @NikhilM not worked

Comment: How are you creating the form? You shouldn't need to add the form or ajax library. Do you have a single function which ends in _form and returns a form render array or are you trying to put a form with HTML etc? It seems like drupal doesn't know your form is a form and therefore isn't including the dependencies.

Comment: For me, the issue was having included jquery twice.

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 8:

```
   function YOURMODULENAME_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
      global $base_url;
      $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/jquery.form';
      $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.ajax';
      $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'MODUL/login_module';
      $attachments['#attached']['drupalSettings']['LoginModuleBehavior']['base_url'] = $base_url;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include the Drupal ajax `drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');`

Comment: where should i inculude this code

Comment: not worked after include this code

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, you may need to include these libraries:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.form');
drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
```

For example:

```
function MY_MODULE_my_form_id($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['#attached']['library'][] = array('system', 'jquery.form');
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = array('system', 'drupal.ajax');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Drupal 8**

Drupal 8 does not include JS-libraries to pages automaticly. So most probably if you meet this error you need to attach 'drupal.ajax' library to your page (or form). Add something like this to your render array:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'drupal.ajax';
```

Comment: This question is about Drupal 7 (see "7" tag). So how does this answer the question?

Comment: When searching about this issue with D8 we can find this page, it helped me, so it's accurate.

Answer (score 1):

#### Drupal 8

For people coming from Google and looking for a D8 solutions, try:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.ajax';
```

Comment: What is the correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

I disabled JavaScript aggregation in the performace config and it fixed my issues with this error in Drupal 8.