# Ajax form submission error when using use-ajax-submit

Tags: forms, ajax, 8

I receive the following message when I attempt to submit a form with `use-ajax-submit` class attached to the submit button:

> An error occurred while attempting to process /my_form?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax: ajax.$form.ajaxSubmit is not a function

Similar to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73544/how-to-fix-this-error-in-drupal-ajax-ajax-form-ajaxsubmit-is-not-a-function), but for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following dependencies need to be added to the library attached to the form in order to use `use-ajax-submit`.

*my_module.libraries.yml*

```
my_module.my_library:
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/jquery.form
```

The library needs to be attached to the form:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_module.my_library';
```